# Listing External And Internal Storage Files

Tags: android, storage

I know how to list the files, but

```
getFilesDir()
```

and

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

both gives internal storage list

Please help me

Full Code

Internal

```
File dir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());

File[] list = dir.listFiles();
String[] name = new String[list.length];
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    name[i] = list[i].getName();
}

ListAdapter adapter = new FilesAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item1, name);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.internal_list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

External

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath());

File[] list = dir.listFiles();
String[] name = new String[list.length];
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    name[i] = list[i].getName();
}

ListAdapter adapter = new FilesAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item1, name);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.internal_list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks

Comment: "both gives internal storage list" -- `getFilesDir()` will return to you files in your portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will return to you files in [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Neither have anything to do with [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: so what can be done for external storage?

Comment: Again, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). My first comment contains links to three blog posts, explaining what internal storage, external storage, and removable storage mean in terms of the Android SDK. I recommend that you read these posts.

Comment: yes i read it. but it doesnt tell me how to use external as i now know abt internal

Comment: "but it doesnt tell me how to use external" -- [the blog post on external storage does](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() is not even there and getExternalCacheDir() does the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106018/discussion-between-devam03-and-commonsware).

Comment: `both gives internal storage list`. So they give both the same list? Well i do not believe that. They will be different.

Comment: It does @greenapps

Comment: Then the used code is not the code you posted here.